# hector_mapping + imu issue

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working with the hector_mapping and hector_imu_attitude_to_tf. After I added the imu node to the system, I haven't been able see any improvement in the estimated map when I force my robot to pitch/roll and the estimated position and map become useless. My robot doesn't provide odometry data. I am not sure if I am renaming the frames correctly, should base_stabilished be declared in my urdf robot file or is it only necessary for the slam nodes?

Here are the launch files I am using:

- example.launch (hector_imu_attitude_to_tf)

  ```
  <launch>
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
  <node pkg="MERLIN_hector_imu_attitude_to_tf" type="imu_attitude_to_tf_node" name="imu_attitude_to_tf_node" output="screen">
  <param name="base_stabilized_frame" type="string" value="base_stabilished" />
  <param name="base_frame" type="string" value="base_link" />
  </node>
  </launch>
  ```
- mapping_default.launch (hector_mapping)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <launch>
  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_stabilished" />
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="base_stabilished"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="20"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>

  <node pkg="MERLIN_hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">

  <!-- Frame names -->
  <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
  <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
      <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />

   <!-- Tf use -->
   <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
   <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
   <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="false"/>
  ```

(rest of the code in this file remains the same)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82991/hector_mapping-+-imu-issue/) by [miguel_sgp](https://answers.ros.org/users/7061/miguel_sgp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was caused by the collision between the robot and the ground, after this was changed the estimated map and position were correct. I set the pub_map_odom_transform to false because there was an error about synchronization but I set to false the use_sim_time as commented and pub_map_odom_transform to true and it's now working. Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [miguel_sgp](https://answers.ros.org/users/7061/miguel_sgp/) with karma: 26 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0